# sqoop won't connect to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, connection

I am trying to connect Sqoop with Mysql. Before I asked this question I have tried all of the solutions I searched for, but nothing worked for me.

This is what I'm typing

> /usr/local/hadoop/sqoop/lib$ sqoop list-databases --connect  jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDb --username Amel --password
> > Amel@-1998;

I do have a SQLConnector installed in /usr/local/hadoop/Sqoop/lib/ directory.

It's called: mysql-connector-java_8.0.25-1ubuntu20.04_all.deb
I had installed the .deb file

this is the error that comes up everytime.

```
Warning: /usr/local/hadoop/sqoop/../hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: /usr/local/hadoop/sqoop/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /usr/local/hadoop/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
Warning: /usr/local/hadoop/sqoop/../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
21/07/09 20:48:11 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7
21/07/09 20:48:11 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
21/07/09 20:48:11 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
21/07/09 20:48:11 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:875)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:59)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.listDatabases(CatalogQueryManager.java:57)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListDatabasesTool.run(ListDatabasesTool.java:49)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
```

Comment: You cannot use the `root` MySQL account without `sudo`. If you need `sqoop` to have full access to the database engine, you will need to create an account with all privileges granted, and use that with `sqoop`.

Comment: I have granted all privileges to ROOT and it still gives me the same errors... I have been stuck on this error for 3 days :(

Comment: As I have already said, you **cannot** use `root`. This is a security issue because people generally use poor passwords, their MySQL databases get accessed by a malicious dolt, and all heck breaks loose. Do not use `root` with applications. Create a new MySQL account for the application with a decent password, and grant that new account the privileges required. `root` is for initial setup and emergency fixing only 

Comment: hello Matigo! I have created a new user and granted all privileges. I have updated my result. I really need your help. Its day 4 stuck on this "Sqoop/MySql connection" problem